# Call to a member function num_rows() on array how to solve this error

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am get error Message:

> Call to a member function num_rows() on array

my controller is

```
 function index() {
        $config=[
            'base_url' => base_url('Users'),
            'per_page' =>5,
            'total_rows' => $this->Useraccount_mod->num_row(),
        ];
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        if ($this->input->post('submit') != NULL) {
            $data = array();
            $data['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
            $data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
            $result['data'] = $this->Useraccount_mod->getUser_list($data,$config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(2));
            $data['userlist'] = $result['data'];
            $this->load->view('Useraccount/Userlist', $data);
        } else {
            $data = array();

            $result['data'] = $this->Useraccount_mod->getUser_list($data,$config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(2));
            $data['userlist'] = $result['data'];

            $this->load->view('Useraccount/Userlist', $data);
        }
    }
```

and model is

```
 function getUser_list($data, $limit, $offset) {
        if ($data) {
            $this->db->like('username', $data['username']);
            $this->db->like('name', $data['name']);
            $query = $this->db->get('users')->limit($limit, $offset)->get();
            return $query->result_array();
        } else {
            $query = $this->db->get("users")->limit($limit, $offset)->get();
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    }

    function num_row() {
        $query = $this->db->get("users");
        $total_rows= $query->result_array()->num_rows();
        print_r($total_rows);

         return $total_rows;
    }
```

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function num_rows() on array
>
> Filename: models/Useraccount_mod.php
>
> Line Number: 41
>
> Backtrace:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$total_rows= $query->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 1):

`$total_rows= $query->result_array()->num_rows();` is where it breaks.

`result_array()` sounds very much to me like it returns an array.

So, refactor:

`$total_rows = count($query->result_array());`

Comment: literally change that line like i said!

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$total_rows= $query->result_array()->num_rows();
```

to

```
$total_rows= count($query->result_array());
```

`$query->result_array()` returns an array and you can get the size using `count`